# NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/KeycloakPrincipal

Tags: keycloak, wildfly-10

I am getting following exception while deploying ear in WildFly 10. Apapter is installed so no jars included in ear & no dependencies set.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/keycloak/KeycloakPrincipal
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal from [Module
>   \"deployment.app.ear.appEJB.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
>           "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
>               "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./App"
>           ]

This issue comes only for classes in  appEJB.jar. The classes in  appWEB.war has no dependency issue.
Here is my subsystem conf:

```
             <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
                <secure-deployment name="appWEB.war">
                    <realm>demo</realm>
                    <resource>app</resource>
                    <use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
                    <public-client>true</public-client>
                    <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8180/auth</auth-server-url>
                    <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
                    <principal-attribute>preferred_username</principal-attribute>
                </secure-deployment>
            </subsystem>
```

Is there any other way to configure ear deployment in subsystem so that ejb.jar also get Keycloak libraries implicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue fixed when I set Keycloak modules dependency for ejb.jar in jboss deployment descriptor.

```
<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-spi"/>
<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core"/>
<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-common"/>
<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error type developing an `Authenticator` for 16.1.0 the specific error being:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.services.util.CookieHelper from [Module "deployment.my-authenticator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader]

The solution was @valsaraj-viswanathan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50442313/6480404). However, I wanted to expand on how to set that.

In `myAuthenticator/src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` I added the following content:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module
                    name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"
                    export="true" />
            <module
                    name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"
                    export="true" />
            <module
                    name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private"
                    export="true" />
            <module
                    name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"
                    export="true" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `MANIFEST.MF` in the META-INF path for the `ejb.jar` project. Write in the file content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-spi, org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core, org.keycloak.keycloak-common, org.keycloak.keycloak-core
```